# Excel VBA - How to find a value in a column and return the row it is on

Tags: vba, excel

I currently use a for loop to look through column A in the HDD database sheet and when it finds the matching search criteria it copies all the information in that row into a designated area.

I am trying to use the same for loop to tell me which row the search criteria is found on so i can delete that row from the HDD database sheet.

Tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

Any help is very welcome on this.

```
Private Sub EditButton_Click()

    Dim Userentry As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    'Dim found As Range
    Dim RowNumber As String
    Set ws = Sheets("HDD database")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("HDD log")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet3")


    Userentry = editTxtbox.Value
    'ws1.Range("A36").Value = Userentry

    For i = 1 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If (ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) = Userentry Then
            ws2.Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8).Value = _
                      ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 8).Value
        End If

    Next i

    addnewHDDtxtbox.Value = ws2.Range("A2")
    MakeModeltxtbox.Value = ws2.Range("B2")
    SerialNumbertxtbox.Value = ws2.Range("C2")
    Sizetxtbox.Value = ws2.Range("D2")
    Locationtxtbox.Value = ws2.Range("E2")
    Statetxtbox.Value = ws2.Range("F2")


    For i = 1 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If (ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) = Userentry Then
            RowNumber = ws.Cells.Row
        End If
    Next i

    ws1.Range("I3").Value = RowNumber

End Sub
```

Comment: The Row property is what you need. [http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/68015-return-row-number-active-cell.html]

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what you want to accomplish when multiple rows match. Do you only want to get the topmost row that matches? Only the bottommost row? All of the rows? Are they all meant to be deleted, or just one?

Comment: There will only be unique values in the column A on the database sheet. The idea is after the results are returned to the log sheet the row in the database is identified and deleted. figured start with trying to figure out which row the unique value is on and then figure the deleting bit out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help. Using Range.Find() should speed it up a little. I can edit this if you want more, just comment.

```
'I liked your found :)
Dim found As Range
'Set found equal to the cell containing your string
Set found = ws.Range("A:A").Find(Userentry)
'Show the row of found if you want
'MsgBox found.Row
'Delete found's row
'ws.found.Rows.Delete
'Alternately, set the value of I3 to found's row
ws1.Range("I3").Value = ws.found.row
```

Comment: keep getting an error with the last bit not sure why though.

Comment: Hi thank you for the info i just needed to put t in the right place. much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem, thanks :) You got it all figured out then? :)

Comment: Yeah seems to be working well just adding new features constantly

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
RowNumber = ws.Cells.Row
```

to

```
RowNumber = i
```